# What formula describes the immediate drop in land value for a gradually-increasing land value tax?

Tags: taxation, land

I am aware that when a government announces that a land value tax will be passed, property values immediately drop.

However, I am curious to know if there is a known formula that approximately determines the percentage drop in land transfer value from before the legislation is announced to after it is passed. I'm specifically interested in a knowing this for a land value tax that is scheduled to increase over time, by a given percentage of ground rent every year.

For example, imagine the capitalisation rate is 5%, and there is currently no property tax or land value tax. The government introduces legislation for a land value tax that increases by 4 percentage points of ground rent every year for the next 20 years, making it eventually reach 80% of ground rent. In this case, what would be the percentage drop in land transfer values?

I suspect that it would be a function of how much tax will have to be payed on the property over the next 20 years (given the 5% cap rate) in comparison to the land value, but with the immediate years being weighted more than the later years.